# Playing .m3u8 file on iOS

Tags: ios, video, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I have `.m3u8` link which I need to play on `iOS` which supports the `HLS Protocol`.

When I assign URL directly to the `MPMoviePlayerController` and play, video is not visible but I can hear the audio.

```
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://qthttp.apple.com.edgesuite.net/1010qwoeiuryfg/sl.m3u8"];
MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
[self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];

if (mp)
{
    // save the movie player object
    self.moviePlayer = mp;
    [self.moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES];

    // Play the movie!
    [self.moviePlayer play];
}
```

What additional stuff do I need to do on `iOS` side?

Comment: first assign `self.moviePlayer = mp;` and the set it to full screen `[self.moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES];` And where is the code for MPMoviePlayerController view added to the screen ?

Comment: @iCoder: Edited the code as per your comment, still no luck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Import:

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
```

Then do:

```
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://qthttp.apple.com.edgesuite.net/1010qwoeiuryfg/sl.m3u8"];
MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];

if (mp) {
    mp.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view addSubview:mp.view];

    // save the movie player object
    [mp setFullscreen:YES];

    // Play the movie!
    [mp play];

    self.moviePlayer = mp;
}
```